# Invalid use of incomplete type in android ndk using c++11 std::async

Tags: android, c++, c++11, android-ndk, cygwin

I tried to use the following function to check whether std::async is supported in android ndk with Eclipse along with cygwin in windows. The function I used is the following

Machine: 64bit win 8 with cygwin

Android: r8e

Eclipse: Juno 4.2.1

ADT: 22.0.1

```
struct Foo
{
Foo() : data(0) {}
void sum(int i) { data +=i;}
int data;
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo;

  auto f = std::async(&Foo::sum, &foo, 42);
  f.get();
  std::cout << foo.data << "\n";
}
```

I get the following error:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
invalid use of incomplete type 'std::__async_sfinae_helper::type {aka struct std::future}' Sample.cpp  /Cli13/jni  line 63 C/C++ Problem

Note: I have set the  _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS and also the **GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X** along with the ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE... By default the ndk uses 4.6 toolchain. I had to include the gnu-libstd++ for 4.7 manually in Properties-> C/C++ -> Includes. Is there any work around to make the std::async working???

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android NDK r8e does not have the full run-time library support of `C++11`. You will need to compile your own NDK using some third-party `stdlib` or wait Google to include the `Clang 3.3` in the NDK which is `C++11` feature-complete.